# Return in Python on Linux Mint fails for Tensorflow Processing Code

Tags: python, ubuntu, for-loop, tensorflow, syntax-error

My python code gives following problem:-

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  file_name = "tensorflow/examples/label_image/data/grace_hopper.jpg"
  ...

  with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    results = sess.run(output_operation.outputs[0], {
        input_operation.outputs[0]: t
    })
  results = np.squeeze(results)

  top_k = results.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
  labels = load_labels(label_file)
  j=0
  for i in top_k:
    print(labels[i], results[i])
    age[j]=labels[i]
    j=j+1
  if age[0] == "youngadult":
    t = 0
  elif age[0] == "youth":
    t = 1
  elif age[0] == "adult":
    t = 2
  elif age[0] == "seniors":
    t = 3
  elif age[0] == "children":
    t = 4
  else:
    t = 5
  return t
```

P.S.
Python - Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Linux- Mint18.3 Cinnamon 64 bit

Cinnamon Version - 3.6.7

Processor - AMD Ryzen5 1600 Six-Core Processor X 6

Memory - 7.8GiB

Hard Drive - 952.7GB

Graphics Card - NVIDIA Corporation Device 1c82

**Error - SyntaxError: 'return' outside function**

Please help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

`__main__` is not a "function" in that you can return something from it.

What are you trying to do and why are you returning?